# Update Arraylist with the value of HashMap present

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, selection

I have an `ArrayList<Model>` type and having fields `id,name,isSelected` and I have one `HashMap` which can store only selected items means if the item is clicked it will be stored in `HashMap<Intere,Model>`, Integer will be id , Model is that object which can be selected. I want to update `Arraylist` item field `isSeleted` to true which is present in `hashmap`. How can i do? I have tried many condition but nothing is working fine.

```
   ArrayList<MainInterestModel> mainInterestList;
    public static HashMap<Integer, MainInterestModel> mainIntrestHash = new HashMap<>();

    Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = mainIntrestHash.keySet().iterator();
    while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        int key = (int) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        MainInterestModel value = (MainInterestModel) mainIntrestHash.get(key);

        int id = value.getId();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainInterestList.size(); i++) {

            MainInterestModel model = mainInterestList.get(i);
            if (model.getId() == id) {

                model.setSelected(true);
                mainInterestList.set(i, model);

            } else {
                model.setSelected(false);
                mainInterestList.set(i, model);

            }
        }
    }
```

By Default `isSelected` is false but when the user will click that item will be stored in `HashMap` later i want to update selection so user interface will show selected items. `HashMap` has selected items and `arraylist` have all items but isSelected are false. at the time of showing selected items, I'm taking `isSelected` is true or not, which working fine, but `arraylist` update is not working.

My adapter class code

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final MainInterestModel mainInterestModel = mainInterestModels.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(mainInterestModel.getName());
    holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(mainInterestModel.getImage());

    // here isSelected is always false because in activity infalting adpter with arraylist, i want to setSeletced by hash object
    boolean isSelected = mainInterestModel.isSelected();
    if (isSelected) {

        holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_selector);

        Log.e("Is Item selected ::", "" + mainInterestModel.getId());

    } else {

        holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bath);

        Log.e("Is Item deselected ::", "" + mainInterestModel.getId());


    }
    holder.ivMainInterest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean selection = mainInterestModel.isSelected();
            if (selection) {

                holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bath);
                mainInterestModel.setSelected(false);
                mainIntrestHash.remove(mainInterestModel.getId());

                Log.e("After Remove SIZE:---", "" + mainIntrestHash.size());

            } else {

                mainInterestModel.setSelected(true);
                holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_selector);
                mainIntrestHash.put(mainInterestModel.getId(), mainInterestModel);


                Log.e("After Adding SIZE:---", "" + mainIntrestHash.size());
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i think you have to put that obj(arraylist's obj) again in hashmap

Comment: @Rohit, when i click item first time, item will be selected and again I click that item will remove from the hashmap. HashMap taking only selected items and everything is working fine but whenever user wants to update intrest so user can see their previously seleted items.

Comment: you want multi selection or single selection ? to store in hashmap ?

Comment: as per your for loop i think only one seletion item in your hashmap ....am i right ?

Comment: as per your description there is no need of hasmap, your work can be done without hashmap

Comment: @MayurKarmur it is multiselection.

Comment: I feel as though you're overcomplicating this by having two collections

Comment: you just need to show selected interests, that can be feasible with arraylist only

Comment: no i have to show all list items with selected items and if user select a selected items, i will be unselected from their intrest

Comment: even you have multiple-level selection that is also feasible with another arraylist in your model class

Comment: yes, @farhana , it is possible with only one arraylist

Comment: @PPartisan how can i manage selection uniqly, i have to keep selected items somewhere, reson behind using hashmap is to avoid duplicacy and all the procedure is doing under adapter class.

Comment: @Rohit I'm using `hashmap` for not containg duplicate items, Arraylist may contain duplicate items, and i cannot change ArrayList, I can update only becuase it is using in Adapter class, if i do something with it will create effect on adapter class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178606/discussion-between-rohit-and-farhana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.ivMainInterest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean selection = mainInterestModel.isSelected();
            if (selection) {
                holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bath);
                mainInterestModel.setSelected(false);

            } else {
                mainInterestModel.setSelected(true);
                holder.ivMainInterest.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_selector);

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

remove hashmap and try to use this.

Comment: I thought about this before, but I didn't try it , It is working. i have to manage list by declaring static so that i can access on previous activity so I declared the list there.

Comment: @farhana You don't need to do that. You have several options regarding IPC and persistent storage that wouldn't require making your `List` `static`. The simplest would probably involve passing it as an `Intent` extra.

Comment: @PPartisan exactly

Comment: @farhana and you have to make that serializable or parcelable

Comment: @Rohit i have made this parcelable.

Comment: @PPartisan I made list static and i never thought that arraylist  would work and i actually forgot that i'm taking a boolean variable that can manage and thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
use  this 

    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class ModelIterator {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ArrayList<mainModel> mainmoldelList = new ArrayList<mainModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            mainModel m = new mainModel();
            m.setId(i);
            m.setName("Rajendra" + i);
            m.setSelected(false);
            mainmoldelList.add(m);
        }

        mainModel m = new mainModel();

        m.setId(0);
        m.setName("Rajendra0");
        m.setSelected(false);

        HashMap<Integer, mainModel> mMap = new HashMap<Integer, mainModel>();
        mMap.put(1, m);

        Iterator<Entry<Integer, mainModel>> ite = mMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, mainModel> pair = (Map.Entry<Integer, mainModel>) ite
                    .next();

            int key = pair.getKey();

            mainModel mObj = (mainModel) mMap.get(key);

            for (int i = 0; i < mainmoldelList.size(); i++) {

                if (mainmoldelList.get(i).id == key) {

                    mainModel tmp = new mainModel();

                    tmp.setId(mainmoldelList.get(i).id);
                    tmp.setName(mainmoldelList.get(i).name);
                    tmp.setSelected(true);
                    mainmoldelList.add(tmp);
                    mainmoldelList.remove(i);

                }

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mainmoldelList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mainmoldelList.get(i).id + " "
                    + mainmoldelList.get(i).name + " "
                    + mainmoldelList.get(i).isSelected);
        }

    }
  }
```